# View in ContainerView in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a project like this:
[image: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/IMG_3307.JPG]

I shared the main screen on the 2nd view:

view from the menu (left)
view with containerview (right).
I would like to display further views in the right containerview (like on the screenshot).

Is this option with containerview possible?
How to do it? Does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add specific ViewController as a subview in Container view

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NameOfVCYouWantToAdd")
addChildViewController(controller)
controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewControllerContainer.addSubview(controller.view)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerContainer.leadingAnchor),
   controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerContainer.trailingAnchor),
   controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerContainer.topAnchor),
   controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerContainer.bottomAnchor)
            ])

controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

> **viewControllerContainer**
>   is the Container View

Answer (score 0):

yes it possible,
just bring that view to top every time you click the menu

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: blablaViewController.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Present specific ViewController as a subview in MainviewController

```
var selectionVc : YourViewController!


func display()
{
    view.perform(#selector(self.view.endEditing(_:)), with: nil, afterDelay: 000.2)

    if selectionVc == nil
    {
        selectionVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController

    }

        selectionVc.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4820205479)

        selectionVc.superVc = self

        // superVc your -- var superVc: mainViewController! 

        self.present(selectionVc, animated: false, completion: nil)


}
```